# class and image id elements not toggling on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got an div ID which includes an image which will act as a toggle point to expand and collapse content for the resulting ID's that reside beneath it.

However I tried to follow a previous 'fiddle' but I'm having troubles implementing it into my project and I can't seem to get it to work.  The image displays but there's no working behavior. There is no errors in the console either. :S

Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="result_location">
            <h3>name and results here</h3><img src="images/minus.png" alt="collapse content icon"></img>

        </div>    
        <div class="result_menu">
            <div id="film_column">
                <h4>('text')</h4>
            </div>    
            <div id="time_column">
                <h4>('text')</h4>
            </div>    
            <div id="genre_column">
                <h4>('text')</h4>
            </div>
               <div id="score_column">
                <h4>('text')</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {

    border:0px;    
    width: 100%;
    }

    #result_location {

    color: white;
    text-align: center;   
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;       
    background: #2c3e50;    
    padding: 10px;             
    }
        img {

            height:0.5%;
            width: auto;
            padding: 0px;
        }

            #film_column, #time_column, #genre_column, #score_column {

             background: #ecf0f1;
             color: black;
             font-size: 1em;
             text-align: center;
             display: inline-block;
             position: absolute-relative;
             width:100%;
             margin-top: 0px;
             float: left;
             width: 100%;                 
            }
```

JS

```
$(".result_location").click(function(){
    $(toggle).next("#result_menu").slideToggle("slow");
})
.toggle( function() {
    $(toggle).children("img").attr("src","images/plus.png");
}, function() {
    $(toggle).children("img").attr("src","images/minus.png");
});
```

Here's the fiddle I was trying to replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/2UuW6/1/

Comment: result_menu is a class, not an ID.

Comment: First step - .result_location should be #result_location. "." targets a class, you have an ID so you need "#"

Comment: its working fine on your jsfiddle.. you made a mistake here only..

Comment: It's funny enough than in jsfiddle you obviously don't use same code as on your site. Before asking question, you should at least show a minimal effort to solve your issue, no?!

Comment: after correcting the class to ID as you rightly mentioned, the container and all elements within it are not visible when returned in browser. "Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined Js Ln 7"

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
$("#result_location").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".result_menu").slideToggle("slow");
    $img=$(this).find("img");
    $img.attr('src',
       $img[0].src=="images/plus.png"?"images/minus.png":"images/plus.png");  
});
```

Comment: Try to explain the changes in your answer? Make it clear for the OP

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this answer, you should downvote the question

Comment: @hduncan what makes you think i'm angry? ;)  Just one thing, if something works somewhere but not somewhere else, try to understand why instead of asking useless question, what do you think about that?

Comment: This worked to some extent, however the image only toggles on the first click. If I try and toggle more than once, the image remains on plus.png

Comment: If I'm stuck, and have tried numerous counts of 'trial and error' does it still class as a 'useless question'?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle appears to work correctly. However you need to check which jquery library you have included in project. Because changing jquery library to 1.10.1 hides toggling element.

**[Fiddle with 1.10.1 jq library](http://jsfiddle.net/2UuW6/2/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```